# How to get VM options in application when running gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jvm-arguments

I run gradle task:

```
gradle test -DtestProfile=dockerTest
```

When I trying to get this variable from application:

```
System.getProperty("testProfile")
```

I get null.

How to correctly get VM options in application?

Some explains.

I have some profiles for running tests in different environments. And different properties for each profile, looking like:

```
application-local.yml
application-test.yml
application-dockerTest.yml
...
```

Each environment should start their own tests depends of its profile. Than, I wrote resolver:

```
class TestActiveProfilesResolver : ActiveProfilesResolver {

    override fun resolve(testClass: Class<*>): Array<String> =
        System.getProperty("testProfile")
}
```

to use it here:

```
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = TestActiveProfilesResolver::class)
```

And I want to send 'testProfile' variable when gradle test starts, with VM variable `-DtestProfile=dockerTest`, for example.

But `System.getProperty("testProfile")` == null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two JVM's to consider here

1. Gradle's JVM
2. The Application's JVM

When you pass a "-D" parameter to Gradle you are setting a system property in Gradle's JVM which is not the same JVM that runs your application

You haven't said how you are running your application yet.

- Are you running the application in a test case?
- Are you running it via the "run" task from the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)?

If you wanted to set the property during tests you'd do something like

```
test {
   systemProperty 'testProfile', 'dockerTest'
}
```

If you wanted to set the system property when running your application via the "application" plugin you'd do

```
apply plugin: 'application'

run {
   systemProperty 'testProfile', 'dockerTest'
}
```

Comment: I run 'gradle test -DtestProfile=dockerTest'. And I need to get this property only as '-D'.

Comment: added some explains at root post

Comment: You still haven't understood. When you set "-D" you are doing this in the Gradle jvm. If you want to specify at command line you'll need logic to pass from the gradle jvm to the test jvm