# When using gradle, I find I cannot have my testcases updated in Rally, as I would when using Maven. How would I do this?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, rally

When using gradle, I find I cannot have my testcases updated in Rally, as I would when using Maven. How would I do this?

Note: I'm using intelliJ as my IDE

In Maven I would use parameters similar to:
`-DrallyIntegration=true` 
`-DrallyEnabled=true` 
`-DrallyUpdateStrategy=async` 
`-DtestBuild=buildDetails_1` 
`-DtestUserEmail=bob@mailinator.com` 
`-DrallyKey=rallyKeyValue` 
`-DtestSetId=TestSetName` 
`-Drally.url=https://url_for_Rally.rallydev.com`

But including these in a gradle run script (in run configurations) does not seem to be picked up on at all.

Comment: You should pass them in your build.gradle script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493682/2960034

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get VM options in application when running gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493329/how-to-get-vm-options-in-application-when-running-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to y.bedrov for the answer.

For clarity , what I needed to do was add the block below to my build.gradle
(note - there are other things defined in the integrationTest task, but the systemProperties are what are needed to get rally integration working)

task integrationTest(type: Test) {

```
systemProperty "rallyIntegration", "true"
systemProperty "rallyEnabled", "true"
systemProperty "rallyUpdateStrategy", "async"
systemProperty "testUserEmail", "bob@woodward.com"
systemProperty "rallyKey", "rallyKeyValue
systemProperty "rally.url", "https://rally1.rallydev.com"
systemProperty "testSetId", "TS102719"
```

}

Also, I included the rally plugin as a dependancy:

```
testImplementation('com.rallydev.rest:rally-rest-api:2.2.1')
```

After rebuilding, my test cases results were updated in Rally